# Array initialization functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, new-operator

I was playing around with C++ and I stumbled upon this problem. I'm trying to initialize an array pointer on the heap, and it works inside the `initialize()`, where it outputs `69`, but in the `main()`, it crashes with the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
#include <iostream>

void initialize(int* array, int size) {
    array = new int[size];

    // Testing
    array[2] = 69;
    std::cout << array[2] << std::endl; // Works fine
}

int main() {

    int size = 3;
    int* array;

    // Initializing
    initialize(array, size);

    // Testing
    std::cout << array[2] << std::endl; // Crash, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    // Cleanup
    delete[] array;
    array = nullptr;


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please help me understand the problem with this.

*Yes, I know I should use `std::vector` but I want to understand why this doesn't work :)*

Comment: For that matter, it crashes at the delete[] function too, with the error text "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: You pass your `array` pointer to your function by value - so when you assign `new int[size]` to it, array in main stays unchanged.

Comment: @MadsMarquart  Well, I'm pretty sure we have a duplicate for this question, I see it asked about 3-5 times a month. Though there might be too many duplicates for it, and we don't have a real canonical Q&A.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you pass `array` to the function, a copy of that pointer is made. When you assign `new int[size];` to `array`, you assign it actually to the argument, which is the copy I was talking about. To really modify the `array` defined in `main`, use references. Change the definition of the function to

```
void initialize(int*& array, int size)
```

or return the pointer like<sup>1</sup>

```
int* initialize(int size)
```

and try it again.

---

I recommend the second method due to its higher expressiveness: something like

```
initialize(array, 3);
```

does not make clear if `array` is modified or not. OTOH,

```
int* array = initialize(3);
```

does.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> as noted by @Jack in the comments to this answer</sub>

Comment: Or directly change the signature to `int* initialize(int size)` if you don't have any specific purpose to set an existing pointer by reference.

Comment: "array to the function, a copy of it it is made."-you may want to clear out that copy of the pointer is made not the whole array itself

Comment: @Giorgi Done, although I think there wasn't much to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the program fails is because you want the memory to be allocated outside the initialize function and the function to operate on that memory.

Simply remove the **new** statement from your function so that it looks like this...

```
void initialize(int* array, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

... then, do your allocation in main and just before the function call...

```
int size = 3;
int* array = new int [size];

initialize(array, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the address of the pointer to avoid the error message